# Remove date from ToDate on selection of fromDate in ng-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I want to clear date from toDate while selecting date from fromDate in ng-bootstrap.

```html
<form class="row row-cols-sm-auto" *ngIf="showDateRangeImp">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker"
                (dateSelect)="impOnDateSelection($event,'from')" [maxDate]="minDate" />
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" (click)="d1.toggle();" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker"
                (dateSelect)="impOnDateSelection($event,'to')" [maxDate]="minDate" (input)="model" />
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" (click)="d2.toggle();" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The Range Selection does exactly what you want: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range

Comment: But how to do it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of clearing the date

- Use ngModel and bind the date picker values to the ts file
- When impOnDateSelection is triggered check the date picker type and rest the model value

```html
<div class="row row-cols-sm-auto" *ngIf="showDateRangeImp">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
        name="dp"
        ngbDatepicker
        #d1="ngbDatepicker"
        (dateSelect)="impOnDateSelection($event, 'from')"
        [maxDate]="minDate"
        [(ngModel)]="fromDate"
      />
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3"
        (click)="d1.toggle()"
        type="button"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
        name="dp"
        ngbDatepicker
        #d2="ngbDatepicker"
        (dateSelect)="impOnDateSelection($event, 'to')"
        [maxDate]="minDate"
        [(ngModel)]="toDate"
      />
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3"
        (click)="d2.toggle();"
        type="button"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
toDate: NgbDateStruct;
fromDate: NgbDateStruct;

impOnDateSelection(value, flag) {
  if (flag === 'from') {
    this.toDate = {
      year: 0,
      month: 0,
      day: 0,
    };
  }
}
```